# 'this' losses context in Node.js HTTP callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope, prototype

The `self.test()` doesn't get triggered inside `http.createServer()`:

```
App.prototype.createServer = function(){
    var self = this;

    var s = http.createServer(function(req,res){

                self.test(); // THIS DOESN`T WORK.

                req.addListener('end',function(){
                    res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type' : 'application/x-javascript'});

                    self.test(); // THIS DOESN`T WORK.
                });

            });

                 self.test(); // THIS WORKS.
    return s;
};
App.prototype.test = function() {
    console.log('test')
};
```

If i move it out of  `http.createServer()` it works. Why is this?
`this` is stored in `self` which should make it not lose context. What am i missing here?
I can provide extra code and more functions (`self.init`, etc) if necessary.

---

## UPDATE

Instance:

```
new App({
    port: 8000
});
```

Initialization:

```
function App(options){
    if (! (this instanceof arguments.callee)) {
        return new arguments.callee(arguments);
    }
    var self = this;
    self.settings = {
        port : options.port
    }
    self.init();
};
App.prototype.init = function() {
        var self = this;
        self.server = self.createServer();
        self.server.listen(self.settings.port);
};
```

Comment: Those functions are simply not reached or `.test` is not what you think it is. Also, `this` never loses scope because it has nothing to do with scope to begin with. Additionally, `self` is a normal variable so it's not accurate to say that `this` loses scope if `self` doesn't work.

Comment: Is it throwing an error or simply not running? If it's not running, have you called app.listen() afterwards? Have you tried making http requests?

Comment: Have you tried passing this into the function?

Comment: @Esailija, my bad. I meant context, not scope. It's been corrected

Comment: @juandopazo, yes, i store all the CreateServer function in a `var` in ìnit()` and call `listen()` on that. The requests are working fine.

Comment: Well, there's nothing wrong in the example code you posted, so I'm guessing you have a bug somewhere else or in the code you removed from the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`req` will emit an `end` event only if it has a body. `GET` requests won't emit it, but `POST` will.

Also, you are supposed to call [listen](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_listen_port_hostname_backlog_callback) to bind your server to a socket. How are you making requests to your server ?

Comment: I answered this in the comments above

Comment: Can you show us how you instantiate `App` and how you call `createServer`? For example, it won't work ff you forget to call `new`. See the [JS garden](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#function.constructors) for more info.

Comment: I reckon it's a problem inside the `createServer` function and has nothing to do with `this`, I tried to `console.log("test")` and it didn`t work either.

Comment: I've tried your code and it works for me. `self.test()` is called correctly. I only added `var http = require('http');`. What version of node are you running ?